# cube does not follow the course of the armature during the animation

Tags: mesh, scripting, armature

I am new to Blender and try to script a primitive snake.

I spawned and constructed the Bones.

I spawned the mesh and connected it with this code:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = (4.5,1,1), scale = (3.5,0.25,0.25))
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj.parent = ArmObj
obj.select_set(True)
ArmObj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ArmObj
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='ARMATURE_AUTO', keep_transform = True)
```

The Problem:

When I start the Animation I scripted this happens:
[image]

The Animation works fine and also the mesh is connected to the armature through the first (root) bone and the last bone but doesnt follow the course of the bones.

My Question:

What do I have to change in the code above that the mesh follows the course of the bones during animation.

Comment: The primitive cube has only 4 faces - no cuts. I would subdivide the cube something like this before parenting to armature: 1. bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = (4.5,1,1), scale = (3.5,0.25,0.25), enter_editmode=True) 2. bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts= len(ArmObj.data.bones)) 3. bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')